# How to test if a list contains part of a string

Tags: c#, list, contains

I have a list of numbers and I have to check if multiple or single numbers of a string are within that list.

For example, suppose I have a list `list = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 5, ... }` with the string `strSegment = "2,8"`.  Trying `list.Contains(strSegment)` clearly doesn't work.  Is there any way I can do this without separating the `strSegment`?

This is the code I have so far:

```
List<string> matchedSegs = ...;
foreach (Common.Ticket tst in lstTST)
{
    string segNums = tst.SegNums;

    var result = segNums.Split(',');
    foreach (string s in result)
    {
        if (matchedSegs.Contains(s))
        {
            blnHKFound = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            strSegsNotFound += tst.strAirSegNums;
            blnHKFound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand you example a little, are you scanning for a sequence of numbers within a list and is that list a long string or a list object?

Comment: In effect of you example are you looking for an 2 followed by an 8?

Comment: Just looking for if "2" exist in "2,8" which it does, but the "2" is in a List string

Comment: I attempted to improve the overall quality of your question.  (It was terrible to be honest)  I tried my best to make sense of it but I couldn't fix everything.  Hopefully I haven't changed the meaning of your question.  _PLEASE_ try to write it better from now on, there's a lot of people willing to help but won't be able to if they can't make any sense of what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *can* do it without splitting the strNumber, but you haven't really explained why you need that. I think splitting then using `Intersect` is the simplest approach and I'd recommend trying this first to see if it is good enough for you:

```
var result = strSegment.Split(',').Intersect(numbers);
```

Here's a more complete example:

```
string strSegment = "2,8";
List<string> numbers = new List<string> { "2", "3", "4", "5" };
var result = strSegment.Split(',').Intersect(numbers);
foreach (string number in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found: " + number);
}
```

Comment: no linq :( just looking to return true if my part of my string is in my string list

Comment: @Sppoks: Why not LINQ? Are you using C# 2.0? Please be more specific about what your requirements *are* rather than what they *aren't*.

Comment: @Spooks: What is the input format for your data? For example, is it a `List<int>` as i guessed in my answer or is it a space separated string? Can you post the code you have tried so far? I think this will make things clearer.

Comment: @Spooks: If you are using C# 2.0, why does your code contain `var`? This keyword was added in C# 3.0.

Comment: @Spooks: I think if `var` works then you are using C# 3.0 or newer and you probably do have LINQ available. Try adding `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file then try my answer again.

Comment: oh yes, all worked, weird, the documentation said  2.0 well, that solves everything. Thanks

Comment: Note: if you want to see what numbers were NOT found, use the `Except` method.